# Problema while en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, while

estoy intentando realizar un while dentro de un .each, el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto en el navegador la pagina queda cargando y cargando y nunca muestra nada, como si entrara en un ciclo infinito. Lo que hace el código es trabajar con horas e ir sumando a una hora de inicio una duración (por lo general son 15 minutos) y mostrar esa suma mientras la hora de inicio sea menos a la hora de fin. Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
<% @prueba.each do |prueba| %>
<% @i = prueba.schedule.hs_start %>

  <% while (@i < prueba.schedule.hs_end) do %>
    <%  @total = prueba.schedule.hs_start + prueba.duration_turn.hour.hours + prueba.duration_turn.min.minutes %>    
    <%= @total.strftime("%H:%M")%>
    <%= @i = @total %>    
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Si el ciclo tarda 15 minutos, entonces la página tardará 15 minutos en cargar y mostrando el final. ¿Exactamente que comportamiento buscas? ¿Puedes mostrar el contenido de la variable `@prueba` para conocer los valores de `schedule`?

Comment: Muchas gracias @Gerry por tu respuesta. Abajo publique la solución que encontré. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera, saque el while por fuera del .each y utilice variables. Espero a alguien le sirva en algún momento. Muchas gracias @Gerry por tu respuesta. Saludos.

```
<!-- uso el .each sobre 'prueba' para traer los valores del select realizado en el controlador y se lo asigno a variables-->
<% @prueba.each do |prueba| %>
    <% @hs_start = prueba.schedule.hs_start %>
    <% @hs_end = prueba.schedule.hs_end %>
    <% @duration_turn = prueba.duration_turn %>
<%end%>

    <!-- creo el link con la hora de inicio de atención y luego sumo a la hora de inicio de atención la duración del turno, mientras la hora de inicio de atención sea menor a la hora de final de atención del prestador -->
    <% while @hs_start < @hs_end do %>
      <%= link_to @hs_start.strftime("%H:%M"), new_calendar_path, data: { confirm: "Seguro?" }%>
      /
      <%  @hs_start = @hs_start + @duration_turn.hour.hours + @duration_turn.min.minutes %>
    <%end%>
```